# Optimal Resting Period for Calisthenics / Bodyweight Training / Gymnastics?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, rest, calisthenics

I've been doing calisthenics for the past year or so, and lately I became quite frustrated as I hit a 3+ months plateau on my l-sit (this is what it looks like in case you're not familiar: https://www.calisthenics-gear.com/calisthenics-exercise-list/#tab-con-34).

I've been stuck on doing it for under 5 seconds. So much so, that I stopped working out for about 2 weeks.

But lo and behold, when I tried again this week, I could hold for over 10 seconds!

So I suspect I've been overtraining. I work out 4 days a week, medium intensity.

My question:

What is the ideal pattern of training for calisthenics- should I train 4 days a week and occasionally take 2 weeks+ breaks? Or train only 1/2 times a week, but go extra hard during those workouts?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's not overtraining but not enough deloading(weeks off). Your Central nervous system can only handle so much, and sometimes your muscles want more that a few rest days. It's customary to take 9 to 14 days off every 6 to 8 weeks. You can line it up with your rest days so that your rest days are part of the deloading so you only have to take a week off. If you have to, you can do a very light weight routine with high reps and half the volume during this time, but I would just take a break.Theres research that this actually helps make you stronger and more muscular taking deloading breaks too.

Also could be sleep? You'd be amazed how much stronger you are after a full night's sleep. When you're working out you should be getting 10 hours a night to help recover your muscles in addition to it's usual work.

4 days a week should be fine for training. As long as youre following the workout program and keeping workouts to 60 to 90 minutes. Also make sure you're not doing too much of one muscle group.. you may not be overtraining your whole body.. but it's possible you might be overtraining a certain muscle that gets used in l sits. I would do your weak exercises first.. maybe you are fatiguing yourself before you do them too.